# load/import fails in mysql due to date format

Tags: mysql, date, types

I am importing data from a .csv file into the table in MySQL, in file there is multiple date columns in the format of 04-05-2017 , which MySQL doesn't accepts.

It fails saying

ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '04-05-2017' for column 'START_DATE' at row 1

Please note that my

|START_DATE             | date          |

is a date column.

Thanks

Comment: Post your `LOAD DATA` code.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE t1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(column1, @var1, column3, ...)
SET column2 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Replace the column with a variable. Then in the `SET` command you convert your string to a proper date.

- read more about load data infile [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
- and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is more information about `str_to_date()`
- and finally [more information about using variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), if you need to have those